# Which value to choose for restrict in Angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Directives** in **Angular** can be used as **attribute name, tag name, comments, or class name**. But, how to decide which type to choose from?

Comment: RTFM ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-restrict- and more generally ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#directive-types

Comment: yes I know restrict values, but which one to choose from, how can I decide?

Comment: See the second link I provided

Comment: sorry @Phil  but https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#directive-types seems not clear

Comment: @ravins, perhaps rephrase the question more concretely. You seem to know what directive styles are supported and how to restrict to certain styles. The links provide quite a bit of additional context. So, what specifically is your concern. Or, put in other words, why is the default `restrict: "EA"` problematic for your needs. Quite honestly, I have no clear idea what exactly you imagine the proper answer to be

Comment: @NewDev there is no problem with `restrict: "EA"`, want to make clear why they created 4 types for it, why not only just  "E" or "A"

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out one of the [many](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#directives) angular [style](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide#directives) guides [on github](https://github.com/gocardless/angularjs-style-guide#directives) to get a good grasp on what a directive should and shouldn't do.

Quoting this [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y074):

> **Restrict to Elements and Attributes**
>
> When creating a directive that makes sense as a stand-alone element, allow restrict E (custom element) and optionally restrict A (custom attribute). Generally, if it could be its own control, E is appropriate. General guideline is allow EA but lean towards implementing as an element when it's stand-alone and as an attribute when it enhances its existing DOM element.

To further this with a bit of my experience with angular, the heaviest use of directives is creating custom HTML element.

```
<my-element></my-element>
```

These usually mean that you will be creating some HTML structure of your own within these tags, and should generally be reserved for partial components, an example being a pie chart created on a few SVG canvases.

If you want to perform some sort of manipulation to a DOM element, if you also are going to create a directive that has its own scope, i.e. you want to send in some options, then I would say using an **attribute** would be best, as it better states your intentions.

```
<div full-screen options="{'top-offset':40}">This should be fullscreen and offset by 40px</div>
```